# Limit PUT acces to a property within an asset

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Instead of giving full update access to a participant I'd like to give him update access to a specific property within the asset.

From what I've read from the documentation it's possible to apply a rule to a property.

**Rule**:

```
rule PatientAddMentor {
    description: "A patient is allowed to add mentors"
    participant(p): "nl.epd.blockchain.Patient"
    operation: UPDATE
    resource(m): "nl.epd.blockchain.MedicalFile.mentors"
    condition: (m.owner.getIdentifier() == p.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}
```

The part where I am stuck at is how to target the asset in the condition.  I'm assuming (m) equals the mentors in the condition because the error message says that the participant does not have UPDATE rights. (I'm not sure if it's even possible.)

**Model:**

```
namespace nl.epd.blockchain

asset MedicalFile identified by bsn {
  o String                    bsn
  --> Patient                 owner
  --> Patient[]               mentors optional
  --> Organisation[]          organisations optional
  o Visit[]                   visits optional
  o String[]                  allergies optional
  o Treatment[]               treatments optional
  o Medicine[]                medicine optional
}

participant Patient identified by bsn {
  o String bsn
  o String firstName
  o String namePrefix optional
  o String lastName
  o String email
  o String telephoneNumber
  o String birthday
  o String gender
  o String city
  o String zipCode
  o String street
  o String houseNumber
  o String houseNumberExtra optional
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACL engine does not yet enforce property level access control (only namespace and class level access control has been implemented).

You will have to use programmatic access control using the `getCurrentParticipant()` runtime API until declarative access control for properties is implemented.